# UITableview get index of each section

Tags: swift

I'm looking to get the index of each section header to be able to delete the contents within the section. But I'm unable to get the index [Below is a screenshot of my UITableview][1]

```
var bookings = [[String]]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 30))
        headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        headerLabel.text = "Booking"
        headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

        let deleteButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:headerView.frame.size.width - 100, y:0, width:100, height:30))
        deleteButton.setTitle("Delete", for: .normal)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        headerView.addSubview(deleteButton)

        return headerView
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if bookings.count == 0 {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You have no bookings" , preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return bookings.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let items = bookings[section]
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let items = bookings[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use the section number as `tag` of the button

```
deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
deleteButton.tag = section
```

In the action get the section index and delete the section

```
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender : UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag
    bookings.remove(at: section)
    tableView.deleteSections([section], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to delete the section from the tableView and reload the tableView?

Comment: I seem to get this error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: Where? The code assumes that there is an outlet `tableView`

Comment: I've 3 func tableView

Comment: You need a connected `IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the title of the section

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let sec = indexPath.section
        let headrer = activityTableView.tableHeaderView?.largeContentTitle
    }
}
```

Or

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     if section == Your section{
         // Your code here
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to access the index of a specific section in your `buttonTapped` method?

One solution is to just subclass UIButton to add a section property:

```
class SectionDeleteButton : UIButton {
    var section: Int = 0
}
```

You can then use this button, instead of the regular UIButton, in your header view and set the section property to the section your header belongs to. And then access this property in `buttonTapped`, via the sender parameter of that method.